# I'm having an issue while trying to compare an object item to object withing an array

Tags: java, object, compare

What I am trying to do is to whether the object (assuming object is long type) is greater than object withing array.

The line with `if( item > queArray[j]) )` point an error saying `The operator > is undefined for argument type(s) T, T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object isn't known to be of `long` type.  All that's known is that it's of some particular type `T`.

Either cast the object to a `Long`, or more generally, use the `Comparable.compareTo` method to compare objects known to be comparable.

Comment: Ok, well doing what your asking does let my code compiles and I guess answer the question of how to fix my problem in my post, but then throws me another problem to solve. Thanks.